# ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder bearer token unauthorized

Tags: powerbi, azure-active-directory, powerbi-rest-api, msal

I am trying to access Power BI web api from my web application. For msal, I can get the correct access token when I use **PublicClientApplicationBuilder** with my organizational email and password.

[image]

but I dont want that. It exposes my email and password.  plus I belive, this method is only suitable for desktop based application. And I need to use an app only access token.It should not be tied to any specific user.

But when using **ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder** with client secret added in Azure app registry, It gives me a different access token which is unauthorized while access anything.

[image]

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

> **Note** that: Client Credential flow works only for Application API permissions.

The "**401 unauthorized**" error usually occurs if the access token does not contain required roles/scopes to perform the action.

**To resolve the error,** make sure to grant application type API permission to the Azure AD Application:

[image]

I generated the access token using the below code:

```cs
var scopesDefault = new string[] { "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default" };
var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
.Create("ClientID")
.WithAuthority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID")
.WithClientSecret("ClientSecret")
.Build();
Microsoft.Identity.Client.AuthenticationResult result = await app
.AcquireTokenForClient(scopesDefault)
.ExecuteAsync();
var text = result.AccessToken;
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

[image]

When I decoded access token, roles are displayed:

[image]

**If still the issue persists,** check the below:

- Few Power BI operations or accessing Power BI requires only delegated admin access token.
- Based on your requirement you can assign delegated Api permissions and make use of Authorization Code Flow to generate access token.
- Create an **Azure Security Group** and add the Service Principal as a Member:

[image]

Enable **`Allow service principals to use read-only admin APIs`** option in Power BI Admin Portal and add Security Group:

[image]

**References:**

[Power BI REST APIs for embedded analytics and automation - Power BI REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/)

[powerbi - Access Token Scope Issue in Azure AD and Power - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75402011/access-token-scope-issue-in-azure-ad-and-power/75407572#75407572) by me